# MySQL - Show only most recent Status of Product

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a brain fart here... I am pulling proper data, however one of my columns isn't pulling the most accurate recent information.

I am pulling two tables together to get information from 'client_educational' and 'client_personal'. The goal here is to get a list of all people who have taken a certain course more than 6 months ago, and show their most recent status: paid, exp-cert (expired certification), pd-cert (paid and certified), void, etc etc

```
client_no    name    email           phone      recent_order_date    status

500000       Joe     joe@mail.com    555-5555   2017-01-02           Paid
500001       Mary    mary@mail.com   555-5555   2017-02-02           exp-cert
500002       Jane    jane@mail.com   555-5555   2017-04-02           pd-cert
500003       Jack    jack@mail.com   555-5555   2017-05-02           void
500004       John    john@mail.com   555-5555   2018-01-02           pd-cert
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
client_personal.client_no,client_personal.name,client_personal.email,client_personal.phone, max(order_date) as recent_order_date, client_educational.status
FROM client_personal
join client_educational client_educational on client_personal.client_no = client_educational.client_no
WHERE product IN ('Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4', 'Product5', 'Product6') 
group by client_no
having recent_order_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 Month);
```

My output is good, however it is not displaying the most recent "status". The goal is to just the most recent "status" for the product listed above. The product above is one product, just different name variations in their system.

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: "Is there a way to do this??" Not ***reliable*** with the current example data.. You can't define a "most recent" in SQL because it requires a order with `ORDER BY` clause.. But without a column which we can use to indentify the order like a id column with auto_increment option or with a datetime colum with default current_time option there isn't a ***reliable*** query.. Besides you are missing example data the SQL query suggest you are using two tables instead of one table.

Comment: ...unless `(client_no,recent_order_date)` is guaranteed UNIQUE

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am moreso looking for someone to point me in the right direction, not hold my hand and do it for me :) I can get it if I know what to research and learn

Comment: @Strawberry client_no is guaranteed unique.

Comment: In the client_educational table?

Comment: @Strawberry yes in both the client_educational and client_personal. client_no is the unique identifier for all clients.

Comment: ? So why are there two separate tables?

Comment: And why do you GROUP BY a unique column? Time to post CREATE statements, sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want people whose most recent of these courses is more than 6 months ago and then you want their most recent overall status.

You can do this using a MySQL `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` hack:

```
select cp.client_no, cp.name, cp.email, cp.phone, 
       max(case when ce.product in ('Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4', 'Product5', 'Product6') then recent_order_date end) as max_date,
       substring_index(group_concat(ce.status order by date desc), ',', 1) as most_recent_status
from client_personal cp join
     client_educational ce
     on cp.client_no = ce.client_no
group by client_no
having max_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 Month);
```

Comment: @Jon Remember to use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet` before using this query.. `GROUP_CONCAT` has a limit default string length limit of 1024

Comment: @Gordon I am receiving an error on this: Error Code 1582 - incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'substring_index'